# Apple Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 and Thunderbolt Display

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I just bought this [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter?fnode=8b)  for my new MacBook Pro (2016) to connect it to my old Thunderbolt Display, but realized that none of my USB ports or Thunderbolt port work (so no daisy-chaining).

Is it something wrong with my setup or is this connectivity not supported by Apple's official Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 solution?

This does not sound like "to Thunderbolt 2" adapter to me, since it only supports multimedia.

Comment: What model is your _old Thunderbolt display_? And what do you mean by _but realized that none of my USB ports or Thunderbolts port work_? Just to clarify, does your display work with this cable? If so, what is it that you're trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: My Thunderbolt Display is from 2012. I just realized that USB/Thunderbolt ports work when I plug the cable off and then plug it on back again, but it works only for ten of minutes and then it stops working. I have to plug it off and on again. I am merely using USB keyboard in my Display and Wacom Tablet so this is really an inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connecting 2 Thunderbolt displays using daisy chain with the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 didn't work for me until I upgraded to the latest Sierra build. (10.12.13) now everything is working as it should. If upgrading didn't work for you I suggest that the adapter is faulty.

Comment: Tried the update and everything works properly now.

Comment: What about the ethernet slot in the display? Is it recognised by the mac?

Comment: Yes. Works fine.